# Name einer Adjektivphrase

Tags: adjective

> Ein **nicht unwichtiges** Argument ist die Tatsache, dass Rauchen das Hungergefühl betäubt.

Wie ist diese doppelte Verneinung im Deutschen (oder auch in anderen Sprachen) genannt?

(Hat das eigentlich einen bestimmten grammatischen Namen? Ich erinnere mich vage an einen Begriff.)

Ich meine Phrasen wie *nicht unschön, nicht untief*, usw. Es ist nicht Pleonasmus (es wäre *weißer Schimmel* oder so etwas), aber denn was? Ich komme nicht auf den Namen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die übliche Bezeichnung ist schlicht *doppelte Verneinung*.

Eine Suche im Web lieferte außerdem [Litotes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes). Dieser Begriff war mir vorher unbekannt, und ich bezweifle, dass er sonderlich verbreitet ist.

*Litotes* ist allerdings nicht einfach synonym mit *doppelte Verneinung*, sondern meint die Verwendung der doppelten Verneinung als Stilmittel, z.B. im Sinne einer Untertreibung. Also etwa wenn man sagt "Ich war nicht unbeeindruckt", wenn man in Wahrheit ausdrücken möchte, dass man sehr beeindruckt war.

Comment: Der Begriff Litotes ist sehr gebräuchlich, es ist in der Literaturwissenschaft _der_ Begriff für das Phänomen.